# Is there a solution for this error `MSB6006`?

Tags: xamarin

`MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. 0`

I have this error

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

`Error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. 0`

I tried to  1 -enable multi_dex

2- downgrade vs to 2019

3- disable   sign the .apk file

4- set code shrinker to r8

5-remove unsupported ( .net 5) run time
6- return to last backup.

and I have searched at many  websites for 7 days  with out benefit .

Note

some of my trails I get the `error  ADB0010`

Comment: Increase build log verbosity. There is usually more to the error than just "java.exe." exited with code.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution
update the jdk to jdk 18 which not supported in vs 2019 but supported in vs 2022
jdk 8 and jdk 10 is no longer supported by the manufacture (oracle) and that cause this problem in my case.